# Java readline() keeping socket open

Tags: java, android, sockets, client-server

I am trying to have my client connect to my server, and depending on the command send some string back to the client. Currently the app connects and can send strings to the server very nicely. However when I send the command which instructs the server to send something back it hangs. I found that the problem occurs when the client attempts to read the line send from the server.

Server

```
 PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
          out.println("GETDATA" + "\n");                
          out.flush();
          out.close();
```

Client

```
BufferedReader fromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));                

        incomingLine = fromServer.readLine();
        Log.d("HERE", "NOT " + incomingLine);
        fromServer.close();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I made effectively [this same mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051198/reading-and-writing-from-a-socket-produces-no-output) when I was first doing sockets as well.

<s>Don't use `PrintWriter` with `BufferedReader`. They're incompatible.</s> By comments, `PrintWriter` actually hides critical exceptions, so they shouldn't be used in networking. Instead, use a `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` for communications.

```
client = new Socket(hostname, port);
inStr = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
outStr = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
```

Then, send and receive using `writeUTF` and `readUTF`, like so:

```
public void send(String data) throws IOException {
    outStr.writeUTF(data); outStr.flush();
}

public String recv() throws IOException {return inStr.readUTF();}
```

The reason has to do with the UTF encoding; a `BufferedReader` expects a certain string encoding, which `PrintWriter` does not give. Thus, the read/write hangs.

Comment: I made the changes
Server Writing to client after request `out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
             out.writeUTF("This");
             out.flush();     `
Client reading whats sent back `DataInputStream inStr = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
          
   incomingLine = inStr.readUTF();`

However it hangs while reading, in this case on the readUTF();

Comment: @user1116969 Hm? You just need to say `out = client.getOutputStream()`. But yes, that should work.

Comment: They're not 'incompatible'. They both use the platform charset by default, and if *those* are incompatible you have a problem. But you can always construct both with the same charset for example. However PrintStream and PrintWriter both swallow exceptions that you need to know about in network programming, so they shouldn't be used over networks.

Comment: Like I said above, made the changes still hangs. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: @user1116969 Any send will wait until there is something to receive data; any receive will wait until something is sending data. Verify that both are happening at the same time.

Comment: So currently the client sends a string over the socket that tells the server it wants a response. Then starts waiting for the response right away. The server checks the command that it received. And then sends the response.

Comment: @user1116969 That's what you *think* happens. You need to find out what is *actually* happening. Or else you don't have a problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The method readLine() expects an end of line character "\n" maybe that's your problem

Comment: Please avoid tiny comments in answer